# I'm getting close to 5000 points on Mathematica stack exchange

Tags: discussion

I accidentally mentioned this to my wife and she asked me how we should celebrate. I wasn't sure if there was a protocol for this kind of thing. But I know how to find the answer -- by asking here!

Update!

[image]

I'm already 1/30 of the way to a million. At this rate, it will only take 105 years to get there!

Comment: A warm glow of satisfaction at a job well done - enhanced by a fermented or distilled vegetable extract of your choice?

Comment: Ask an interesting, hard question on main? :)

Comment: Celebrate by initiating your wife. To StackExchange. A new experience. And a change of life.

Comment: So what did you do in the end?

Comment: @cormullion It was an exciting day... some fermented liquids, introduced Ann to "Great Outdoors" stack exchange, missed the exact 5000 point (so no good picture). Sorry J.M., I thought I had a really good question, but then just before posting, I figured it out. Thanks for all the good suggestions. Who knows, someday maybe I'll reach 10K...

Comment: 5000 came and went very quickly.  You've been busy!  I think 10K will be here before you know it.

Comment: Congrats on 10K - pretty fast work, and presumably twice as many festivities!

Comment: Looks like I was right regarding 10K.  Congratulations!

Comment: Good job! Next stop: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S5L5Q.png =)

Comment: @rm -rf If I ever reach the exalted level of Aleph-naught, I suspect Mr. Wizard will be several dozen Aleph-ones ahead!

Comment: I often wonder how it is possible to earn a 5 or 6 figure reputation, it must be a fulltime job: the mods must be retired ( software ) millionaires or Wolfram employees. I don't care: I am very grateful for the help I got from mma stackexchange.

Comment: @niloderoock, if they're Wolfram employees, then they're considerably less busy than I am. :)  I am just...crawling...almost to 10k.  Clearly, I am just lazy!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try to hit 5,000 reputation exactly, and take a picture.  Or pick a humorous or interesting number for your milestone:

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image] 
[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: 11000]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: 98999_rep]

Also, the real "celebration" starts at 10,000 -- celebration for the moderators that is, because you'll see all the deleted junk and (1) have sympathy for us (2) accept the mantle of responsibility for reviewing our delete actions. :^)

Comment: I see I'm not the only one :D [10,000](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=4256200#4256200), [20,000](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5475998#5475998), [39,999](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dUbji.png) (fell short by 1)... I also remember hitting 15k and 30k exactly (don't know how I managed it multiple times), but don't recall if/when/where I shared it.

Comment: @rm-rf I added one of yours.

Comment: Hehe, I just realized... 10k was so long ago! Szabolcs hit first in mid March '12, soon followed by you, Leonid, Heike and me within the next month. Sigh... good times, when you were just 2k within reach :P

Comment: So now I know what "access to moderator tools" that's promised on the Privileges page for reaching 10,000 really means. I _knew_ there was a catch.

Comment: @m_goldberg, y'know it was once said that when you find what you're looking for, you sure do want it less...

Comment: For determining what an iteresting number is, you may want to consult an expert http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_%28number%29

Comment: @belisarius -- It's easy to prove (by contradiction) that there is no uninteresting integer. Suppose there was one; then there is a smallest uninteresting integer. Surely, that's an interesting property. QED.

Comment: @bills Not all subsets of an unbounded set are bounded, sorry :)

Comment: @bills great comment! I suppose you meant natural numbers, but ok :). That is a great statement to get people (me) into number theory!

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I wanted to join `6` party today but I had 6667, so I decided I will downvote one of your answers :D, "unfortunatelly" I got next upvote and I left this idea :P

Comment: @Kuba we don't have an all-sevens image yet; try to hit 7,777 -- you'll be there very soon at your present rate!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wish me luck and competence :)

Comment: @Kuba ha! I actually saw that you had only a bit less than 6666, I actually thought making a joke that you should downvote something, but the next time I looked you had more than 6700 :P. Crazy stuff :)

Comment: @Kuba You're getting close; don't forget.  You may need to do some tactical Accepting and/or answer-downvoting to align at 7.  (I'm sure you can find some bad answers if you look hard.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah! I had to downvote and unaccept Jacob but it was worth it :P

Comment: I thought some unlucky numbers were worthy of this post.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom your last edit hurts my brain :)

Comment: I have not been around much lately but this was 50001 was something I never thought would eventuate...happy MMA using everyone

Comment: @ubpdqn Congrats!  On behalf of the community thank you for your contributions. :-)